# Javascript reliable create and delete function

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to develop a CRUD tool. However, the logic I am using to pursue this is problematic. You can find my [full JSFiddle in this link](https://jsfiddle.net/87zL4d6n/21/).

My HTML looks like so:

```
<p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
<div id="moregohere"></div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```

When you click on `remu` you should delete the corresponding p class. For some reason clicking on the last `remu` errors out. `cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`. Not sure why that's happening.

However, there is another issue here. Which is that when I click on `generator`, I want to generate a `remu` that can be deleted by clicking on it, in much the same way as the ones already generated.

The problem is that at some point the generated `remu` stops responding to my clicks. My conclusion to this is that wrapping my functions inside `(function(i){//function here}(i))` only makes it correspond to whatever functions are already present at DOM creation.

This also makes sense since I am using the `remove()` protocol to remove from the DOM elements that I have deleted. But my script really doesn't work very well.

For reference, my code:

```js
var remu = document.getElementsByClassName("remu");
var generator = document.getElementById("generator");
var moregohere = document.getElementById("moregohere");

generator.addEventListener('click', function() {
  moregohere.innerHTML += "<p class='remu'>Added Fish</p>";
  removal();
});

removal();

function removal() {
  for (i = 0; i < remu.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      remu[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        remu[i].remove();
      });
    }(i));
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
<div id="moregohere"></div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need that IIFE approach, just bind the event `click`.
- Use `this.remove()` instead of `remu[i].remove()` to avoid variable `i` scope problems.

```js
var remu = document.getElementsByClassName("remu");
var generator = document.getElementById("generator");
var moregohere = document.getElementById("moregohere");

generator.addEventListener('click', function() {
  moregohere.innerHTML += "<p class='remu'>Added Fish</p>";
  removal();
});

removal();

function removal() {
  for (var i = 0; i < remu.length; i++) {
    remu[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.remove();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
<div id="moregohere"></div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```

Comment: @DaveCousineau because of this: `moregohere.innerHTML += "<p class='remu'>Added Fish</p>"`

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML so that your `<div>` is holding all of the elements.

```
<div id="moregohere">
  <p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
  <p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
  <p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
</div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```

There are more effective way to handle elements and bind events to objects on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that when you call `removal()` after adding a fish, you don't remove the old event listeners from the `remu` elements that were in the original HTML. And when you remove elements, their indexes in the `remu` NodeList change. So you end up removing multiple elements with different indexes.

This isn't a problem for the elements in `moregohere`, because your use of `innerHTML +=` recreates the whole DOM in that DIV, but the original elements are not affected.

As Ele points out, you can use `this` in the event listener to refer to the element that was clicked on, so you don't need to deal with indexes. But you should also remove the old listener to keep it from running twice. Using a named function as the listener will make this possible.

```js
var remu = document.getElementsByClassName("remu");
var generator = document.getElementById("generator");
var moregohere = document.getElementById("moregohere");

generator.addEventListener('click', function() {
  moregohere.innerHTML += "<p class='remu'>Added Fish</p>";
  removal();
});

removal();

function removal() {
  for (i = 0; i < remu.length; i++) {
    remu[i].removeEventListener("click", removeThis);
    remu[i].addEventListener("click", removeThis);
  }
}

function removeThis() {
  this.remove();
}
```

```html
<p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
<div id="moregohere"></div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some massive problems with your current approach.

The self-removing elements are bound to their index number, as was correct when they were added.

But the `remu` collection updates as elements are added/removed. So the indexes will not stay accurate. For instance, you cannot remove an element which originally had an index higher than the number of remaining ones!

Also, you are attaching the event listener multiples of times - again bound to the index. So if you add a new item, which re-binds the event handlers, and then remove the first Fish 0 (item 0) it will remove item 0 twice. I.e. also remove Fish 1. Add 5 new ones and then remove item 0 and it will take another 5 with it!

You need to maintain the state of your CRUD objects much more securely than the `remu` result, and also avoid binding handlers more than once.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete Fish 1, the length of remu array will be changed. remu[3] (Fish 2) will be undefined. Please try the code below. :)

```js
var remu = document.getElementsByClassName("remu");
var generator = document.getElementById("generator");
var moregohere = document.getElementById("moregohere");

generator.addEventListener('click', function(){
 moregohere.innerHTML += "<p class='remu'>Added Fish</p>";
 removal();
});

removal();

function removal(){
 for (i = 0; i < remu.length; i++){
  const currentRemu = remu[i];
    currentRemu.addEventListener('click', function(){
      currentRemu.remove();
     });
   
 }
}
```

```html
<p class="remu">Fish 0</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 1</p>
<p class="remu">Fish 2</p>
<div id="moregohere"></div>
<p id="generator">Generator</p>
```